# Which permissions should i include when i use admob android

Tags: java, android, admob

Which permissions should i include when i use admob "android" to make it using user location to improve earning from ads?
i am using these permissions and features

```
  <meta-data
        android:name="ADMOB_ALLOW_LOCATION_FOR_ADS"
        android:value="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
```

What permission unneeded in my case? I dont want app ask user to use location when he install it and let admob using location data at the same time

Comment: You need two permissions: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/> and you also need to  should include following namespace code in the Layout tag :

xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"

Comment: @FadySaad thanks for reply but what about ?    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to include any special permissions to use AdMob when building an Android app. The SDK comes with its own manifest file with the appropriate permissions, and these will be included in your app's final APK automatically via [manifest merging](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html).

There's currently a bug in Android Studio that can cause a warning about permissions to appear when using the Mobile Ads SDK, but your app should still compile and run just fine. Our official sample for [Native Ads Express](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/blob/master/admob/NativeExpressExample/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml) has no permissions in its app manifest, for example, but still loads and displays ads correctly.